# How come some messages attract this much user?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

Following question attracted 4k visitors:

[How to ask for a bank account "upgrade"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/how-to-ask-for-a-bank-account-upgrade)

In average a question has fewer than 100 visitors. I try to understand which questions will attract users for what reason but 4k is way too much from my point of view, is there any other referrer which lists selected messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions including the one you had mentioned [are chosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) to be listed network wide in the list of

[Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)

Our site gets nicely promoted by this but those questions will of course get much more views (and votes).

Also see

- [What is the Goal of "Hot Network Questions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions)
- [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)
- [Change Hot Network Questions algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295583/change-hot-network-questions-algorithm)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting it has this much effect, probably worth to think about influencing the algorithm to publish posts which are really worth it from the perspective of GL.

Comment: Yeah - small sites with few views or questions suffer a bit form unbiased votings on HNQ but the views reflect how many we could reach if we were interesting enough. Cheating an algoritm may not be a good idea in the long run but showing more love to interesting questions can't be wrong ;P